# Call state in another component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to know how to call the contents of the updated state that are in another component?

I have an `auth.js` file:

```
state: {
  admin: [],
  token: '' // token default null
},
actions: { 
  async authIN({ commit }, admin) {
    try {
      ...
      commit('SET_TOKEN', response.data.token) // after submit
      ...
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
},
mutations: {
  SET_TOKEN(state, newtoken) {
    state.token = newtoken;
    console.log("this-> new token ", state.token) // token already has its contents
  }
},
getters: {
  settokens: state => state.token
},
```

and in `app.vue`:

```
<v-app class="grey--text text--darken2" id="defaultFont">
  <v-main>
    <h2>ini , {{token}}</h2>
    <router-view />
  </v-main>
</v-app>

import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  data: () => ({
    drawer: true,
    token:''
  }),
  components: {
    NavA,
    Loader,
    NavB,
  },
  mounted () {
    this.settokens()
  },
 computed: {
   ...mapGetters('Auth',['settokens'])
 },
};
```

How can I pass the contents of the state token in `auth.js` to `app.vue`?
I am using Vuex version 2. can you help me?

Comment: can you show you root state file?, you might be using namespaced modules if yes, try `...mapGetters('auth', ['settokens'])`, where auth is the namespace

Comment: I want to display the contents of the state token on the app.vue page

Comment: in `app -> computed` add `token () { return this.$store.state.token; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.vue` you can import your Vuex getters:

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
```

Then, in `computed`:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['settokens'])
}
```

This way you can access it from anywhere in `app.vue`.

Comment: I did, but <h2> this ->, {{token}} </h2>
null

how to call it on mounted ()

Comment: you can use  `this.settokens `

Comment: I have updated the code above, I wrote this.settokens mounted

and I get an error that is this.settokens not function

Comment: `settokens` is a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Looks like you want to remove the `token` property in `app.vue` altogether. Get rid of `mounted` and try `{{ settokens }}` in your `h2`.